# How to set default values for multiple xml preferences?

Tags: android, xml

There are 2 xml preferences files with separate settings..

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(file1)  //works
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(file2)  does not work
```

Second files default values are not loaded and I think that's expected..

How to call PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues for 2 different files, ensuring it will be executed only once..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up with below hack..

```
final SharedPreferences defaultValueSp = context.getSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

    if(!defaultValueSp.getBoolean(PreferenceManager.KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES, false))
    {
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.file1, false);
       //passing true as ignored otherwise because of above call
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.file2, true); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interface Editor for modifying values in a SharedPreferences object. Ex method :

```
public static void setPreferredArtistName(Context context, String artistName) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("ArtistName", artistName);
        editor.commit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the first `false` and the second `true` like this:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.file1, false);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.file2, true);
```

Comment: What about third one?